# .keyword being added to all fields in Kibana for Elasticsearch visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have some data in Elasticsearch (version 6.7), many of the field docs are keywords using `boolean` similarity.  And when I look at the data in the discover tab it looks great.

However when I go to visualization, and try to do a histogram by one of those fields (`browser_name` for example).  The field name now looks like `browser_name.keyword`.  And the query comes back with no results.

When I inspect the query I see it is in fact using the `browser_name.keyword` value and when I change it manually I do get data back (some screen shots below).  Can someone tell my why the visualization tool is adding this in?

This shows the browser name as the field label (and some sample values as I can see from the Discover view)

[image]

And this is from the visualizations tab where it's giving me the `.keyword` appended (and cannot be overridden)

[image]

And, as mentioned earlier, if I inspect my network tab and grab the query directly I get

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "browser_name.keyword",
        "size": 5,
        "order": {
          "_count": "asc"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "script_fields": {},
  "docvalue_fields": [
    {
      "field": "timestamp",
      "format": "date_time"
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": 1568520000000,
              "lte": 1569038399999,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "timeout": "30000ms"
}
```

Which also has the bad field name.  If I change this to `browser_name` I get the results I would expect to see

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find an answer to solve my problem on https://discuss.elastic.co/t/terms-aggregation-in-kibana-visualization-keyword-field-not-found/115693

By refreshing the index pattern the index fields popularity counts were updated and this allowed me to visualize them properly